# Monaco Editor Incorrectly Detecting Brackets

Tags: monaco-editor

How can I tell Monaco not to recognize my brackets when they are part of certain tokens? For example, my language has an arrow operator `=>`.

[image: token angle bracket highlight]

As far as I could tell from looking at the source, 'standard' tokens named 'comment' or 'string' will automatically not be searched for brackets. I noticed that C# in VS Code does not seem to consider `<>` as brackets. Is this currently a limitation that cannot be worked around?